# ABBYY OCR library recognition only number IOS?

Tags: ios, ocr, text-recognition, abbyy

I am creating number recognization in ios on real time. I have found one ABBYY OCR library This is very good and fast but this is recognization both text and number but I want to only number recognization. Please help me. how can I do this?. From StackOverflow I have found one hint we can use `English.edc`  file from `dictionaries` But this file is lock and can't able to open. What is the solution?  please share your valuable knowledge with me .

Comment: You can set language to Digits if you are using Cloud OCR SDK. Which SDK are you using?

Comment: Thank you For help, I have found a solution myself.